# Term for "avoiding reality"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, pejorative-language

Is there a single word which describes someone who is trying to hide from the truth? 
For example, when my acquaintance's father died, she went on living and believing that her father was still alive and was on an overseas trip. What is the term for this condition?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In that context it's called *denial*.

> **denial** *-n*
>   A psychological process by which painful truths are not admitted into an individual's consciousness

Comment: Did she believe her father had taken a trip to Egypt?  Maybe a river cruise?

Comment: @MT_Head cringe :D

Comment: Couldn't help it.  I have mummy issues.

Comment: +1 That's a perfect word in this context. Denial is the first stage of the [5 stages of grief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model) (or coping with someone's death): denial, anger, bargaining, depression and acceptance.

Comment: Example usage, "My acquaintance is living in denial of her father's death."

Answer (score 1):

I think Bogdan's suggestion of [escapism](http://www.wordnik.com/words/escapism) fits the bill

> **noun**
>
> The tendency to escape from daily reality or routine by indulging in
>   daydreaming, fantasy, or
>   entertainment.

so that person would be an [escapist](http://www.wordnik.com/words/escapist)

> **noun**
>     Someone who wants to escape; especially from reality

Comment: This is a related word, but it does not really apply to the OP. I will update my post with a definition.

Answer (score 1):

In my view "delusion" would be an appropriate word to describe your example.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the [excellent suggestion of *denial*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/term-for-avoiding-reality/25672#25672), other workable terms:

- irrational
- disconnected
- lost
- out of touch
- crazy